# Perl delete a character from a string unless it is a duplicate

Tags: perl, substitution

What is the cleanest/simplest way to remove a particular character from a string **unless** it is repeated once.

For example given the following string:

```
'it''s 'simple'
```

I expect:

```
it's simple
```

For my usage there shall never be more than two ' characters in a row.

Comment: What should happen for the string `it""s "simple"` ? What do you mean by "duplicate" ? What should happen for the string `mississippi` ? Should it become `misisipi` ?

Comment: ... also, what should happen for `it'''s simple` ?

Comment: @Corion the ' character is being used as an escape character but also to quote the string... This is from an xlsx formatted document (the actual xml) - worksheet names My actual example has one less ' but it seems Microsoft both quote and escape using the ' char. don't ask me why!!

Comment: If this is CSV, you should be using Text::CSV, setting the quote char and the escape char to `'`.

Comment: @ikegami Unfortunately its not. Text::CSV is great though (I'm using it to create a csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead assertion.

```
#!/use/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$_ = "'it''s simple'";

say;

s/'(?!')//g;

say;
```

`'(?!')` means "a single quote that isn't followed immediately by another single quote".

Output:

```
'it''s simple'
it's simple
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! That's definitely simple - It's quite amazing what you can achieve with regex!

Answer (score 2):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $text = q!'it''s 'simple'!;
$text =~ s/'('?)/$1/g;
print "$text\n";
```

So in the regex `'('?)`, it will match - and remove - the first `'` and if followed by another, will capture it and place it in the result.

This version will handle each one or two apostrophe group separately (because OP used the term "duplicate" instead of "multiple"). If you want to replace any 2+ apostrophe sequence with a single one, use the regex `'('?)'*` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Silvar. I've updated my question to mention that there will never be more than two chars in a row, but this will probably be useful for others!